# generate rand value belonged to two different ranges

Tags: java, random

I need to generate random values using `Random` object. It generates values from 0 to 1, but I want to generate random values that fall into the ranges `[0,10e-7]` and `[10e-7,1]`.

Comment: In what ratio for each range? 50/50?

Comment: if the ratio is random, then logically the there is only one range: `[0, 1]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
double max, min; 
if (Math.random() > .5) { // adjust ratio of ranges here
    min = 0;
    max = .00000001;
} else {
    min = .00000001;
    max = 1;
}
double random = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `nextDouble()` method of the `Random` class to get a number between 0 and 10e-7.

Then, in the first case, divide the number by 10e7 to get a value in the [0, 10e-7] range and add 10e-7 to the generated value if it is lower than this value for the second case.